# Where is the configuration actually saved in the system?

Tags: 8, webforms, configuration

I am new to Drupal 8. I installed the Drupal webform module. I am able to export the configuration file but unable to figure out where the configuration is actually is saved in the Drupal system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere, most of configuration is located in database including webform.

With config module, you may find webform configuration in admin (yml) : `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`

First, select webform in configuration type, then the configuration you need to export.

NB : have a look at sources https://github.com/drupalprojects/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/src/Entity/Webform.php , most of drupal contributions are built the same way, webform extends `ConfigEntityBase` and these are typically stored in database (`config` table as a blob)